# Learning words simple programme

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to make a programme that takes words from the user, puts them in a list and then prints the amount of unique words that the user entered. The programme prints out the unique words when it receives a blank input. This is what I wrote.

```
amount = []
nuword = input('Word: ')
while nuword != '':
  nuword = input('Word: ')
  if nuword in amount:
    amount.pop(-1)
  else:
    amount.append(nuword)
print('You know',len(amount), 'unique word(s)!')
```

Is there a simple way to print all of the unique words in a list. Like some kind of function? Or do I have to change something in the loop?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = {}

nuword = 1
while nuword:
    nuword = input("Word: ")
    if nuword not in counts: counts[nuword] = 0
    counts[nuword] += 1

uniquewords = []
for word, count in counts.items():
    if count != 1: continue
    uniquewords.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal candidate for [sets](http://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php), which are similar to lists, but only contain one copy of something.

Example set usage:

```
words = set()
words.add('apple')
words.add('bee')
words.add('apple')
print(words)
> {'apple', 'bee'}
```

Here is your code slightly modified to use sets

```
amount = set()
nuword = input('Word: ')
while nuword != '':
    nuword = input('Word: ')
    amount.add(nuword)
print('You know',len(amount), 'unique word(s)!')
```

I would also recommend considering the case of beginning/trailing spaces and upper/lower case. Right now, all of the following will count as their own word

```
abc
 abc
abc  
aBc
```

(Hint, the 3rd one had trailing spaces) We'll use some handy methods to get rid of the whitespace and turn to lower case.

```
' aBc   '.strip().lower()
> 'abc'
```

With all the edits:

```
amount = set()
nuword = input('Word: ')
while nuword != '':
    nuword = input('Word: ')
    amount.add(nuword.strip().lower())
print('You know',len(amount), 'unique word(s)!')
```